# color transition on hover but not on focus/active?

Tags: css

I would like my button to have a background/font-color transition when I hover it, but not when I am clicking it (active).

Currently I have the transition effect on both hover and active.
I tried adding `transition: 0s ease-out;` on either :active or :hover but I didn't get the expected result.

What is correct, cleanest and simplest way to do this (by using css) ?

```css
button {
 position: absolute;
 width: 80px;
 height: 28px;
 font-size: 13px;
 font-weight: 700;
 line-height: 28px;
 color: #6cb4d5;
 font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
 padding: 0;
 border: 0;
 border-top-right-radius: 3px;
 border-bottom-right-radius: 3px;
 border-left: 1px solid #CCC;
 background-color: #fff;
 transition: 0.3s ease-out;
}

button:hover {
 color: #f7f7f7;
 background-color: #6cb4d5;
    outline: 0;
}

button:active {
 color: #f7f7f7;
 background-color: #398cb2;
 outline: 0;
}
```

```html
<button type="submit" name="sub-avatar-url" id="sub-avatar-url">&ensp;UPLOAD</button>
```

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this https://jsfiddle.net/2Lzo9vfc/93/

```
button {
    position: absolute;
    width: 80px;
    height: 28px;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: 700;
    line-height: 28px;
    color: #6cb4d5;
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    border-top-right-radius: 3px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 3px;
    border-left: 1px solid #CCC;
    background-color: #fff;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
}

button:hover {
    color: #f7f7f7;
    background-color: #6cb4d5;
    outline: 0;
}

button:active {
    color: red;
    background-color: blue;
    outline: 0;
    transition: none;
}
```

Comment: Hum thanks for your answer, but that is not what I am looking for. As you saw in my snippet I use a darker background-color when the button is active, but I am only trying to get rid of the transition animation between when the button is hovered, and when it is clicked (and active). ;)

Comment: Oh so you want transition on hover but not on active

Comment: Updated my answer so please take a look.

Comment: Had the same idea as yours with my `transition: 0s ease-out;` :) unfortunately it only works when the button is clicked, but not when unclicked : / edit: I might still use this if eventually I can't find the perfect solution

Comment: Ok now i get what you are saying and after some research i don't think it's possible. As soon as you release button that transition from hover kicks in. But i might be wrong and i would also like to know answer. Great question btw.

Comment: Yes, without using javascript I don't think this is possible, unless I work it around by displaying a new button over the old one when it is "active", but this is not exactly "clean and simple", thanks anyways !

Comment: This is what i got but dont know how to put that :after on place of original button https://jsfiddle.net/2Lzo9vfc/97/

Comment: Not yet, that would be interesting provided the button doesn't automatically un-active itself when the :after is displayed because of the z-index, but I don't think I will go that far for a simple background transition tbh, it wouldn't be worth it, especially if there are several buttons :/

Comment: It works ! you just typed `absolute:` instead of `absolute;`, Not sure if I will implement it since it is a pretty hacky way haha but I mark it as the answer since I feel this is the closest we can possibly get ! (add it to your answer), anyways good job :) Thanks a lot !

Comment: No problem, glad i could help if i did at all. This was really interesting to figure it out and much more complex then i first thought it will be :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want the button to go back to it's original colors on button:active, then adding in the original values to the :active block will correct this.

However, if you want to display the colors you have while hovering over the button while active, simply removing the :active block will give that effect.

Both are here next to each other. Hopefully this is what you wanted. :)

https://jsfiddle.net/2Lzo9vfc/94/

```css
button {
 position: absolute;
 width: 80px;
 height: 28px;
 font-size: 13px;
 font-weight: 700;
 line-height: 28px;
 color: #6cb4d5;
 font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
 padding: 0;
 border: 0;
 border-top-right-radius: 3px;
 border-bottom-right-radius: 3px;
 border-left: 1px solid #CCC;
 background-color: #fff;
        transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
}

button:hover {
 color: #f7f7f7;
 background-color: #6cb4d5;
        outline: 0;
}


#sub-avatar-url2:hover {
        color: #f7f7f7;
 background-color: #6cb4d5;
        outline: 0;
}

#sub-avatar-url2:active {
        background-color: #fff;
        color: #6cb4d5;
        outline: 0;
        transition: none;
}
```

```html
<button type="submit" name="sub-avatar-url" id="sub-avatar-url">&ensp;UPLOAD</button> <br><br>
<button type="submit" name="sub-avatar-url2" id="sub-avatar-url2"> &ensp; UPLOAD</button>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, unfortunately it's none of both :/ I'm looking to display a darker blue (as seen in my css) when the button is active. Your second exemple is the closest to what I could get in terms of transition (transition effect still appears when unclicking)

Answer (score 1):

This May Help you-

```
button {
    position: absolute;
    width: 80px;
    height: 28px;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: 700;
    line-height: 28px;
    color: #6cb4d5;
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    border-top-right-radius: 3px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 3px;
    border-left: 1px solid #CCC;
    background-color: #fff;
    transition: 0.3s ease-in;outline: 0;
}

button:hover {
    color: #f7f7f7;
    background-color: #6cb4d5;
    outline: 0;
}

button:active {
    color: #f7f7f7;
    background-color: #398cb2;
    outline: 0;transition:all 0ms ease-out
}
button:focus{transition:all 0ms ease-out}
```

Comment: This is actually very close from what I want indeed, the only problem I see is that the button doesn't has his transition back after I clicked it, when I un-hover it. I marked the question as answered but I'm still interested if someone finds another solution.

Comment: button:focus{transition:all 300ms ease-out}

Comment: same result :/   - i'll dig into that

Answer (score 0):

You could try applying the `transition: 0s;` to the active statement - however, you also need to add in the `:focus` event to the declaration chain to prevent the button transitioning when you release the click.

You can see the fiddle here:
http://jsfiddle.net/eks8Lc5c/

Comment: thanks for your answer, but I don't really like the use of :focus on a button, since the button stays "pushed" after releasing the click